# Как обратиться к inline кнопкам которые находятся в функции

Tags: python, функции, aiogram, button, inline

У меня есть функция в которой созданы 2 кнопки.

```
def buy_menu(is_url=True, url='', bill=''):
    qiwi_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    if is_url:
        btn_url_qiwi = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ссылка на оплату", url=url)
        qiwi_menu.insert(btn_url_qiwi)

    btn_check_qiwi_ = InlineKeyboardButton(text="какой-то текст", callback_data="check_" + bill)
    qiwi_menu.insert(btn_check_qiwi_)
    return qiwi_menu
```

Как мне отловить нажатие этих кнопок в коде?
Я знаю как работать с кнопками вне функции (то бишь кнопка просто создана и находится вне функции)
Допустим если инлайн кнопка создана не в функции, ее нажатие можно отследить, например так:
Так создана кнопка:

```
btn_pay = InlineKeyboardButton(text='=какой-то текст', callback_data='pay')
```

Так я отслеживаю ее нажатие:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'pay')
async def process_callback_button_pay(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
```

В общем сейчас я не понимаю как сделать тоже самое, но для инлайн кнопок которые находятся в def
Если что плохо объяснил/написал спрашивайте. Я только учусь так что я гриб на данном этапе
Использую aiogram

Comment: url кнопки ты не отследишь никак

Comment: по факту мне не нужно отслеживать url, нужно просто отловить нажатие кнопки которая находится внутри функции

Comment: Нет, вам нужно отследить нажатие на кнопку, которая является ссылкой. И это реализовать невозможно средствами BotAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветик! Я так понимаю, нужно проверить статус чека? Я бы сделал отдельный хендлер и в нем проверял бы статус чека.
Как-то так:

```
    from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
    p2p = QiwiP2P(auth_key='ТОКЕН КИВИ')

    def buy_menu(url:str, bill_id:str) -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
        qiwi_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        if url:
            btn_url_qiwi = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ссылка на оплату", url=url)
            qiwi_menu.insert(btn_url_qiwi)
    
        btn_check_qiwi_ = InlineKeyboardButton(text="какой-то текст", callback_data="check_" + bill_id)
        qiwi_menu.insert(btn_check_qiwi_)
        return qiwi_menu
    
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='check_')
    async def checkpayment(call: types.CallbackQuery):
        bill_id=call.data.split('_')[1] #БЕРЕМ ID ЧЕКА
        bill=p2p.check(bill_id)
        if bill.status == 'PAID':
            billinfo=int(float(bill.amount))
        else:
            billinfo=False
    
        if billinfo == False:
            await call.answer('Оплата еще не получена!', True)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Мы получили оплату')
            #делаем действие
```

Решение рассчитано на: `aiogram`+`pyqiwip2p`
Данные для `buy_menu` можно создать так:

```
    bill=p2p.bill(amount='цена', lifetime='жизнь ссылки', comment='коммент') 
    keyboard=buy_menu(bill.pay_url, bill.bill_id) #цена и жизнь - числа
```